# How to get a Google Places API key?

Tags: google-places-api

How do I get a Google Places API key? Must I pay or can I get a dummy for free? I want to obtain an API key for the "Find Place" request https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place

Comment: By "OpenAPI token" do you mean a [Google Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/get-api-key)?

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow the guidelines at Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/get-api-key

The documents are comprehensive, if not a little difficult to navigate.

From memory it's roughly along the lines of;

1. Create a Google account
2. Sign up to the Developer account (click the Get Started button in the top link)
3. Enter your credit card details (needed even if you are only expecting minimal use...)
4. Turn on the Google Places API within your account
5. Create an API key within your account and configure it with relevant restrictions according to your needs

Comment: The greatest problem on URL routing is the graph-related structure, hard for humans to traverse...